# How to keep observations match after value label modified?

Tags: label, match, stata, lookup-tables

I'm doing some basic data processing stuff with Stata. However, I get stuck on how to keep the observations of the other variables matching, after modifying a variable's value label.

For example, say, I have the raw dataset as follows:

```
   var1   var2   var3
    US    1000    15
  China    500    20
    UK     800    10
```

The *var1* is a string variable. I need to convert it into a numeric one. So I typed

```
   encode var1, gen(country)    // where the new variable country is numeric
```

The variables that I want for future work are *var2*, *var3* and *country*.

When the new variable is generated, it automatically has a value label. To be specific, if I click on US in the column of *country*, it shows 3 in the cell on top of the column.

```
   var1   var2   var3  country
    US    1000    15     US
  China    500    20   China
    UK     800    10     UK
```

So far it's good. I mean for each row the observations match.

However, this automatically generated value label is not exactly what I want. What I need is to make 1 denote UK, 2 for US and 3 for China. So I modified it by:

```
     label define country 1 "UK" 2 "US" 3 "China", modify
```

As shown below, I get the value labels that I want. Like, a click on China gives me 3.

```
     var1   var2   var3  country
      US    1000    15    China
    China    500    20     UK
      UK     800    10     US
```

But the point is, as you may already notice, the order of the observations for *country* is arranged alphabetically. It makes the corresponding values of *var2* and *var3* for each country to be wrong.

That is exactly where I could not get through. Since the columns that I finally need are *var2*, *var3* and *country*, I'd like to have each country with its corresponding values of *var2*, *var3* and as well the customized value labels.

I tried *sort*, *order* and a couple of commands but none gave me the result. I don't know what command I should use or there's something wrong in my earlier work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `label()` option of `encode`, is one way:

```
clear
set more off

input ///
str10 var1   var2   var3
  US      1000    15
  China    500    20
  UK       800    10
end

label define lblcountry 1 "UK" 2 "US" 3 "China"
encode var1, generate(country) label(lblcountry)

list
list, nolabel
```

See also the user-written command `sencode` (*super*-encode), which can do more: `ssc describe sencode`.